# Who are these characters in Star Wars Rebels?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In the newly launched *Star Wars Rebels* TV series (which takes place 14 years after Order 66), there are two characters:

> a trained Jedi and a force sensitive kid.

Who are these guys? Have they ever been mentioned in any existing canon (including EU)? Or, are they new creations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### THIS POST CONTAINS LINKS THAT LEAD TO SPOILERS!

[image]

*From top to bottom, left to right: Zeb, Sabine, Kanan, Ezra, Chopper and Hera.*

#### The characters appear to be new creations designed to appear in the period five years BEFORE the Star Wars Saga but after the time of the Clone Wars series. It is claimed that great effort was made to [keep the work within canon](http://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page) and there is a novelization of the two main characters, Kanan Jarrus and Hera Syndulla, called A New Dawn by John Jackson Miller and published by Random House/Del Rey.

**Ezra Bridger:** A thief, vagabond, and teenage scamp who discovers Kanan and his crew in the middle of a job on his homeworld. Kanan was engaging in the theft of Republic goods. Ezra makes a nuisance of himself interfering with the Republic stealing gear and equipment for his hideaway. His involvement with Kanan’s crew appears to be an accident. At first. He reminds me of Disney’s Aladdin minus the monkey and genie. Love the slingshot.

> He appears to be a budding Jedi appearing to be able to without training, hear a holocron, open it and already has some ability with faster than normal reflexes and one hell of a force jump.

**The rest of the cast is far less developed from the first outing.**

**Kanan Jarrus:** Leads this group of rebel survivors on missions of mercy, helping out victims of the Republic’s new grip after the events of Order 66. Cool under fire, one hell of a shot with a blaster and drives a speederbike like he was born on it. From the promotional materials, Kanan weilds a lightsaber, so he is possibly a survivor of Order 66.

**Hera Syndulla:** The Twilek pilot, spends the bulk of her time on the small ship the crew uses, something that appears only a tiny bit larger than the Millennium Falcon. Same complement of weapons and some minor shields capable of holding off four Tie Fighters for over five minutes. Appears to have a strong and friendly relationship with the group leader Kanan. REF: [Hera Speaks: Newsrama.](http://www.newsarama.com/20414-hera-speaks-star-wars-rebels-vanessa-marshall-on-pilot-plot-and-family-dynamic.html)

**Sabine:** Demolitions expert with a penchant for leaving her mark on things, literally. Skilled with a variety of demolition materials, Sabine appears to love her work and enjoys every chance to exercise her skill. Her armor has a distinctively Mandalorian appearance.

**Zeb:** Large, intimidating, foul-smelling and those are his good traits. He’s the team heavy and uses the biggest weapons he can find. He’s not quite as large as a Wookiee but he’s far more understandable. He’s good with his hands and quite excellent in hand to hand combat. Has the shortest temper and attention span of the group. Energetic and enthusiastic, he is likely to end up a favorite.

**Chopper:** Not the friendliest of droids; while he doesn’t speak, his whistles, tweets and groans make his unhappiness with people very apparent. He is, however, quite adept at security systems and can man (er…droid) a gun turret like a pro. He negotiates zero-g quite effectively and can tow a friend if he needs to. Like Artoo, he is a good droid to have around.

**Agent Kallus:** appears to be a fiercely intelligent Republic Operative sent out to investigate crimes that appear to have a systematic approach to them. He is impulsive, quick to anger, but reasonably capable. If he were a bit more calm, he would likely be twice as effective. He appears to be one of the recurring enemies of the story.

**The Inquisitor:** We get to know nothing about him in the first episode other than he is in charge. I am certain he will reveal only what we need to know for quite some time. His distinctive appearance and markings put me in mind of Darth Maul.

Disney has managed to keep the wraps on these characters revealing some short clips on their Disney XD page: [Star Wars: Rebels](http://disneyxd.disney.com/star-wars-rebels/characters)

#### Novelization: A New Dawn

[image]

Written by John Jackson Miller

> - The novel (my first Star Wars work since Kenobi) is set several years after Star Wars: Episode III – and several years before the upcoming animated television series Star Wars: Rebels. As you can see from the cover, two of the main characters of that series, Kanan and Hera, have major roles in the book.
> - This is the first novel integrating input from the [Lucasfilm Story Group](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lucasfilm_Story_Group), which manages story concepts across all media, and so in addition to working with Random House’s team I both got inspiration and feedback from the series’ executive producers, Dave Filoni, Simon Kinberg, and Greg Weisman, as well as Pablo Hidalgo, Jennifer Heddle, and Leland Chee. **[REF: John Jackson Miller’s Website: Faraway Press](http://blog.farawaypress.com/2014/04/my-new-novel-star-wars-new-dawn-rises.html)**

#### Other Materials

Other materials from previously published canon such as [The Inquisitor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Inquisitor), the [Imperial Security Bureau](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Security_Bureau), and [Sienar Fleet Systems](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sienar_Fleet_Systems) are story elements in the new animated series, and all these ideas find their origins in roleplaying game material published in the 1980s.

Comment: Looks like the villain was already in existence.. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Inquisitorius